# Verify 64 bit binary on windows

Tags: windows, binary, 64-bit

How can I verify that a .exe file is built for 64 bit on Windows ? I am used to Linux where I can simply use the 'file' command to see this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into the file using a HEX editor. There's a `PE` magic signature somewhere after the DOS stub, and the platform ID is close behind (some bytes later). For 64 bit builds, it is `0x8664` or so, which is quite easy to spot.

Comment: Thanks, for me it say 64 86. There are some description of the values at this page http://www.vowles-home.demon.co.uk/utils/windows_file_exe.htm and also links to windows versions of the file command.